# CET/CEST time shift is dropped when exporting from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, posixct

I run into a problem with summertime when exporting time series from R to Excel using openxlsx, where summertime is not retained in the excel file.

The data frame contains times stored in POSIXct format with timezone set to "CET". As per convention, time shifts one hour forward on the third Sunday of March 02:00 to switch to summertime (CEST). As a result, 2019-03-31 01:00:00 CET is followed by 2019-03-31 03:00:00 CET, while 2019-03-31 02:00:00 CET does not exist.

CET/CEST switches work as expected in R, but are not retained in the excel file resulting from it. As an example, when running:

```
require(openxlsx)
CEST_test<-data.frame(date=c(as.POSIXct("2019-03-31 01:00:00", tz="CET"),as.POSIXct("2019-03-31 03:00:00", tz="CET")))
write.xlsx(CEST_test,"CEST_test.xlsx")
```

The resulting excel file ignores the switch to CEST, resulting in an erroneous non-CET time indication on the third row:

[image: non-existing time in excel]

I've tested this on a macOS and on a Windows 10 system, with identical results.
Would anyone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
require(openxlsx)
options("openxlsx.datetimeFormat" = "yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss %Z")

dd <- c("2019-03-31 01:00:00", "2019-03-31 03:00:00")
CEST_date <- as.POSIXlt(dd, tz = "CET")
CEST_date <- format(CEST_date, usetz = TRUE)
CEST_test <- as.data.frame(CEST_date)
write.xlsx(CEST_test,"CEST_test.xlsx")
```